# Do the same interval just laggier in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a html canvas game and I use requestAnimationFrame.
My problem is that in fast computers it runs at full speed (60 fps)
But in slower computers it runs slower like 10 fps, and then the game slowes down.
I want to do it at the same speed just do it laggier.
Like in minecraft, w.o.t. or l.o.l., the zombie comes to you at the same speed, just laggier if you use worse computer.

Sorry for my English and Thanks for the answers!

Code removed.

Comment: Have you bothered looking at the argument that `requestAnimationFrame` passes to your callback?

Comment: So that's a "no". `requestAnimationFrame` passes a parameter to your callback that tells you exactly how much time has passed. Use this to judge how far the game state should move along.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that different computers will not call the update and the draw methods at the same rate. This is why you need to calculate the time elapsed between the last update to make your animations "go faster" to catch up. You can have a great example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame